# read.table cut off a long row into half. how to reorganize the cvs file

Tags: r, csv, rstudio

```
c <- read.table("sid-110-20130826T164704.csv", sep = ',', fill=TRUE, )
```

so I use the above code to read about 300 csv files.
and some files look like this

```
65792,1,round-5,72797,140,yellow,75397,192,red,75497,194,crash
86267,1,round6,92767,130,yellow,94702,168,brake,95457,178,go,95807,185,red,96057,190,brake,97307,200,crash
108092,1,round-7,116157,130,yellow,117907,165,red
120108,1,round-8,130173,130,yellow,130772,142,brake,133173,152,red
137027,1,round-9,147097,130,yellow,148197,152,brake,148597,160,red
```

As you can see the second is longer than other line (for each row the third element is supposed have round#) and when I do read.table R cuts the line in half, below I copied the first 5 columns from R

```
9                86267               1  round-6  92767 130
10               95807             185      red  96057 190
11               108092               1  round-7 116157 130
12               120108               1  round-8 130173 130
```

is there a way to edit that so that the row is one line instead of being split?

Comment: I'm guessing you need to put something in there to specify the number of columns you expect. `read.table` only checks the first few lines to determine how many columns to expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can prime the data.frame width by specifying "col.names" argument along with "fill=TRUE" as in:

```
c <- read.table("sid-110-20130826T164704.csv", sep = ',', fill=TRUE, 
            col.names=paste("V", 1:21,sep=""))
```

That's assuming you know how many columns you have. If you don't know, you might want to make a single pass through the file to find the maximum width.

Comment: thanks that works awesome. Another tricky part is that my goal is to import like 300 files into one giant table, and some files have 12 columns and some have 18 columns, or even more. is there a way to find out what's the maximum columns width of all the 300 files using R?

Comment: You could use `readlines` and `strsplit` to read them in one line at a time and use `rbind` to append new rows (for every line) and `cbind` to append new columns (only when the current line has more records than the large matrix you are growing). It would look like:

Comment: Easier would be to use a system command to append all the files together and read in once.